# AWS VPN not releasing tunnel connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpn

I am trying to setup a VPN client in AWS using Keycloak and Google OAUTH as my IDP.  I can log into the VPN just fine and a connection is established but once I disconnect from the AWS VPN Client I am unable to log back in.  The connection is stuck on "re-establishing" and it never seems to move from there.  It almost seems like the connection to the AWS tunnel is not released as I am unable to access any AWS consoles.  The only fix I have been able to find is to disconnect from my WIFI and re-connect.  Has anybody encountered this before?  As a side point we have separate VPN endpoint that uses user/password authentication and I can log on and off to my hearts content.  There are no noticeable difference between the two VPN endpoint configurations